# Is this legal/safe?

Tags: c#, security

Suppose I do this:

```
Span<char> span = new char[4096];
Span<byte> bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(span);

RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(bytes);
```

Can I still use `span`? What if `RandomNumberGenerator` fills `span` with values that are invalid for a `char`?

Would this be safe?

Comment: No values are invalid for `char` - every value from U+0000 to U+FFFF is a valid for for a `char`. (It might not be a valid Unicode value, but .NET doesn't really care directly.)

Comment: char is just an unsigned 16bit value... it doesnt care if its printable or not.

Comment: Ah ok. That sounds good. Thanks

Comment: As others have noted, this is *legal*, but if you intend to use the resulting `span` for any kind of string that might go outside your process, it may well have surprising effects. In particular, using a value like that for a password or key of some sort will likely fail since many system will choke on strings with NUL characters in them, at the very least. In other words, you are at the very least doing something *dubious* by not simply keeping things as a `Span<byte>`.